# How to search lines above/under of X lines of a string?

Tags: string, bash, search, grep

Well, I've got a masive file like this:

```
vi file1 

            xxx
                 xxxxxxxxx           xxxxxxxxxx          xxxxxxxxxx
            O48     
                 8.80620265          3.13576702         16.73758145
            O49     
                 2.11414472          0.47922554         23.80825532
            H1      
                 1.09354199          0.56015908         23.18883965
            H2      
                 1.84841487          0.60605486         24.87784867
            O50     
                 6.45693524          0.12577435         26.20766069
            H3      
                 5.43633251          0.20670789         25.58824502
            H4      
                 6.19120539          0.25260367         27.27725405
            O51     
                 3.85207272          4.89778259         29.52091127
            H5      
                 2.83146999          4.97871613         28.90149560
            H6      
                 3.58634288          5.02461191         30.59050463
            xx 
                 xxxxxxxxx           xxxxxxxxx          xxxxxxxxx
```

That I want to do, is simply search 2 lines above from the string "H1" (i.e. O49 in this case), and print from this line to the end.

I tried something with `grep` but it doesn't work properly.
Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Poz '(.*\n){2}.*H1.*(\n.*)*' file
```

Output:

```
           O49     
                 2.11414472          0.47922554         23.80825532
            H1      
                 1.09354199          0.56015908         23.18883965
            H2      
                 1.84841487          0.60605486         24.87784867
            O50     
                 6.45693524          0.12577435         26.20766069
            H3      
                 5.43633251          0.20670789         25.58824502
            H4      
                 6.19120539          0.25260367         27.27725405
            O51     
                 3.85207272          4.89778259         29.52091127
            H5      
                 2.83146999          4.97871613         28.90149560
            H6      
                 3.58634288          5.02461191         30.59050463
            xx 
                 xxxxxxxxx           xxxxxxxxx          xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is less than 1000 lines:

```
grep -B2 -A1000 'H1' file
```

Comment: what about `grep -B2 'H1' file | head -n 1`

Comment: @git that will print *only* `O49`. If you don't know a maximum line count for the file, you could do `grep -B2 -A$(cat file | wc -l) 'H1' file`, but that requires the file to be read twice.